# How do I shrink an objects array, merge duplicate properties into one but stacking unique properties into an array? In Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am looking to find the best way to iterate over an objects array, combining all uniquely occurring property strings into an array, but only on objects that share all of their other properties. Thus, effectively "stacking" similar objects on top of each other. A difficult one to explain in prose but the example below should make it clear (actual data changed for readability):

Input:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joey",
    "book": "1",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joey",
    "book": "2",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "book": "3",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "book": "4",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "book": "5",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sean",
    "book": "6",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sean",
    "book": "7",
    "personType": "a trait"
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Joey",
      "book": ["1","2"],
      "personType": "a trait"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "book": ["3","4","5"],
      "personType": "a trait"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sean",
      "book": ["6","7"],
      "personType": "a trait"
    }
  ]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Will having different people with the same name create problems?

Comment: Yes @traktor - as the desired output listed above will then be merged with another objects array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Joey",
    "book": "1",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joey",
    "book": "2",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "book": "3",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "book": "4",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "book": "5",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sean",
    "book": "6",
    "personType": "a trait"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sean",
    "book": "7",
    "personType": "a trait"
  }
]

const res = data.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
  if(acc[cur.name]){
    acc[cur.name].book.push(cur.book);
  }else{
    acc[cur.name] = {
      name: cur.name,
      book: [cur.book],
      personType: cur.personType
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const out = Object.values(res).map((val) => val);
console.log(out);
```